# select distinct column, priority second column value

Tags: oracle, group-by, distinct

I want to select distinct/group by column and show for the second column only one value(out of 3 possible) priority by: if `A` appears in the group show it, if not show `B`, if not show `C`.

This is the table:

```
A       B
----    -----
FST     A
FST     B
FST     C
INCS    C
INCS    B
ASW     A
AWR     C
WER     C   
WER     C
WER     B
```

RESULT

```
A       B
----    -----
FST     A
INCS    B
ASW     A
AWR     C
WER     B
```

Comment: Are you using a particular flavour of sql?

Comment: oracle 11g, optimized as possible..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For your given data, the easiest way is:

```
select A, min(B)
from table t
group by A;
```

For the more general problem where alphabetic ordering is not correct (if you wanted to return 'B' ahead of 'A', say), you can do this with `case` statements:

```
select A,
       (case min(case B when 'A' then 1 when 'B' then 2 when 'C' then 3 else 4 end)
             when 1 then 'A'
             when 2 then 'B'
             when 3 then 'C'
             else '???'
        end)
from table t
group by A;
```

EDIT:

Oracle has an easier way to do this than the nested selects:

```
select A,
       max(B) keep (dense_rank first
                    order by (case B when 'A' then 1 when 'B' then 2 when 'C' then 3 else 4 end)
                   ) as BestB
from table t
group by A;
```

Comment: Is there a way to integrate `LIKE` operator into the `case` operation?

Comment: @nir: Yes. `CASE WHEN B like 'A%' THEN 1 WHEN B like 'B%' THEN 2 ...`